# Relay Modern and Join Monster

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern

After reading [Sashko Stubailo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280944/stubailo)'s post "Exploring Relay Modern" it seems apparent that one of the more important enhancements of Relay Modern is the query compiler. The compiled queries remove duplicate references and can be stored on the server and referenced from the client using a hash. This prevents every user from having to send the exact same query to the server which can be a [huge savings](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14142196) for high traffic web services.

Join Monster reduces roundtrips by creating gnarly JOIN queries by inferring SQL schema from the a decorated GraphQL schema. It really fetches just what you want based on your GraphQL query.

Are these two technologies complimentary or incompatible? Will using Join Monster bypass the optimizations of relay-compiler? Are the optimizations of Join Monster likely more important for lower traffic web services?